# Warning: mssql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given - SQL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

No sé si me puedan ayudar o no se entienda mi pregunta, se las dejo de igual manera, tengo el siguiente error:

> Warning: mssql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in usr/home/FFFF/pago-tarjeta_paypal.php on line 111

La linea en sí es esta:

```
/*************************************************
 * ACTUALIZAR DATOS GRABAR TRAS VOLVER PAGO PAYPAL
 * EXEC [dbo].[EnviosGrabarFormaDePago] 
 *************************************************/
/* Conectar con el procedimiento almacenado */
$stmt21       = mssql_init('EnviosGrabarFormaDePago');
/* Parametros pasados al procedimiento almacenado */
$ControlError = '';
$EnvioID      = NULL;
$FormaPago    = 37;
$FechaPago    = date("Ymd");
$referencia   = $_GET['tx'];
mssql_bind($stmt21, '@ControlError', $ControlError, SQLVARCHAR, true, false, 40);
mssql_bind($stmt21, '@EnvioID', $EnvioID, SQLINT1);
mssql_bind($stmt21, '@IdentificadorEnvio',$_GET['ie'],SQLVARCHAR,false,false,25);
mssql_bind($stmt21, '@FormaDePago', $FormaPago, SQLINT1);
mssql_bind($stmt21, '@FechaDePago', $FechaPago, SQLVARCHAR, false, false, 19);
mssql_bind($stmt21, '@ReferenciaPago', $referencia, SQLVARCHAR, false, false, 40);
mssql_bind($stmt21, '@MontoPago', $_GET['amt'], SQLFLT8);
/* Ejecutamos el procedimiento */
$resultado21 = mssql_execute($stmt21);
$row         = mssql_fetch_row($resultado21);  // Aqui esta el error 
/* Liberar los recursos */
mssql_free_statement($stmt21);
```

En mi DB esta así

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[EnviosGrabarFormaDePago]
    -- Agregar los parámetros para el procedimiento almacenado aquí
    @ControlError           VARCHAR(max) OUTPUT,
    @EnvioID                INT,
    @IdentificadorEnvio     VARCHAR(25),
    @FormaDePago            INT,
    @FechaDePago            DATE,
    @ReferenciaPago         VARCHAR(40),
    @MontoPago              DECIMAL(10,2)

AS
BEGIN

    -- Evita que se devuelva el mensaje que muestra el recuento del número de filas afectadas 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY

        --INSERT INTO [dbo].[Prueba] ([Tipo],[Datos]) VALUES ('EnviosGrabarFormaDePago', '--------------------------------------')
        --INSERT INTO [dbo].[Prueba] ([Tipo],[Datos]) VALUES ('EnviosGrabarFormaDePago @EnvioID : ', CAST(@EnvioID AS varchar(10)))
        --INSERT INTO [dbo].[Prueba] ([Tipo],[Datos]) VALUES ('EnviosGrabarFormaDePago @IdentificadorEnvio : ', @IdentificadorEnvio)
        --INSERT INTO [dbo].[Prueba] ([Tipo],[Datos]) VALUES ('EnviosGrabarFormaDePago @FormaDePago : ', CAST(@FormaDePago AS varchar(10)))
        --INSERT INTO [dbo].[Prueba] ([Tipo],[Datos]) VALUES ('EnviosGrabarFormaDePago @ReferenciaPago : ', @ReferenciaPago)
        --INSERT INTO [dbo].[Prueba] ([Tipo],[Datos]) VALUES ('EnviosGrabarFormaDePago @MontoPago : ', CAST(@MontoPago AS varchar(10)))

        -- Inserte las declaraciones para el procedimiento aquí
        SET @ControlError = ''

        DECLARE @Comentario             VARCHAR(800)    = ''
        DECLARE @UsuariosSistemaID      TINYINT         = 1
        DECLARE @EstadoID               TINYINT         = 49
        DECLARE @TotalEnvio             DECIMAL(12,2)   = 0

        -- 36   TARJETA DE CREDITO
        -- 37   PAYPAL
        --  0   PAGO NO COMPLETADO / ERROR / CANCELADO

        IF @IdentificadorEnvio <> ''
        BEGIN 
            SELECT @EnvioID = EnvioID, @TotalEnvio = Total FROM Envios WHERE IdentificadorEnvio = @IdentificadorEnvio
        END

        IF @EnvioID <> 0
        BEGIN 
            SELECT @IdentificadorEnvio = IdentificadorEnvio, @TotalEnvio = Total FROM Envios WHERE EnvioID = @EnvioID 
        END

        --INSERT INTO [dbo].[Prueba] ([Tipo],[Datos]) VALUES ('EnviosGrabarFormaDePago @EnvioID Verificado : ', CAST(@EnvioID AS varchar(10)))

        IF @EnvioID <> 0 AND @FormaDePago <> 0
        BEGIN

            UPDATE Envios SET FormaDePago = @FormaDePago, FechaDePago = @FechaDePago, ReferenciaPago = @ReferenciaPago, MontoPago = @TotalEnvio 
                WHERE EnvioID = @EnvioID

            SET @Comentario = 'Registro de Pago (Referencia) - ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(@ReferenciaPago))
            SET @EstadoID = 49      -- 49   Registro de Pago
            --INSERT INTO [dbo].[Prueba] ([Tipo],[Datos]) VALUES ('EnviosGrabarFormaDePago @EnvioID <> 0 AND @FormaDePago <> 0 : ', @Comentario)

        END 

        --INSERT INTO [dbo].[Prueba] ([Tipo],[Datos]) VALUES ('EnviosGrabarFormaDePago @FormaDePago : ', CAST(@FormaDePago AS varchar(10)))

        IF @FormaDePago = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @EstadoID = 39      -- 39   Envío Anulado
            SET @Comentario = 'Envío Anulado - Registro el Pago'            
        END 

        IF @EnvioID <> 0
        BEGIN

            DECLARE @FechaEnviosSeguimientoInsert DATETIME = GETDATE()
            DECLARE @ActualizaEstadoEnvio         BIT      = 1
            EXECUTE [dbo].[EnviosSeguimientoInsert] @ControlError OUTPUT, @EnvioID, @Comentario, @UsuariosSistemaID, @EstadoID, @FechaEnviosSeguimientoInsert, @ActualizaEstadoEnvio

            IF @MontoPago <> @TotalEnvio
            BEGIN
                SET @Comentario             = 'Total de Transferencia : ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(CAST(@MontoPago AS VARCHAR(10)))) + ' - ' + 'Total del Envio : ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(CAST(@TotalEnvio AS VARCHAR(10))))
                -- SET @ActualizaEstadoEnvio    = 1
                EXECUTE [dbo].[EnviosSeguimientoInsert] @ControlError OUTPUT, @EnvioID, @Comentario, @UsuariosSistemaID, @EstadoID, @FechaEnviosSeguimientoInsert, @ActualizaEstadoEnvio
            END

        END

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        -- Cierre del cursor
        CLOSE cEnviosDetalle
        -- Liberar los recursos
        DEALLOCATE cEnviosDetalle

        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        -- Control de Errores
        SET @ControlError = ERROR_MESSAGE(); 
        INSERT INTO LogErrores (Numero, Mensaje, Procedimiento, Linea) VALUES (ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_MESSAGE(), ERROR_PROCEDURE(), ERROR_LINE())

    END CATCH;

END
```

En qué podría estar fallando, tenia más errores pero los solucioné, este me esta dando dolores de cabeza.
Es un procedimiento almacenado, me olvidaba decirlo.

Saludos,

Comment: Has probado el procedimiento directo en la BD? funciona?

Comment: Sí, o sea, hay muchas más conexiones, pero en esta nada más tengo ese problema y no sé por qué la cause.

Comment: El error es porque tu execute te estará regresando false, esto es porque la consulta está mal, si dices que el procedimiento jala bien, prueba revisando las variables de tu código

Comment: Puede ser un problema de permisos. Ese error a mi me lo suele dar cuando la query no se está ejecutando, o cuando da un valor nulo